# How can I pass a value in flask and still keep all the new lines and spaces?

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask, codemirror

How can I pass a value in flask and still keep all the new lines and spaces?

I have a template with a textarea and a button, when I press the button, I want to be redirected to a flask page with the text inside the text area without losing any newlines and spaces. Let's say I have the text:

```
This is the first line

This is the third line

This is the fifth line
    This is the fourth line, I also have a character for more space
```

I have tried replacing all the new lines with \n then, pass along the formatted string, and in the python script, replace \n with actual line breaks. But the output is:

```
This is the first line

This is the third line

This is the fifth line
This is the fourth line, I also have a character for more space
```

Notice how the fourth line lost it's space?
I did it using this js code:

```
let confirmUri = "{{ url_for('confirm_page') }}";
let str = editor.getValue(); /* this is a codemirror editor's value */
str = str.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '\\n');
window.location.href = confirmUri + '?authorization=supersecretcode&text=' + str;
```

Comment: If you're displaying it in a web page, it needs to be in a `<pre>` block or you have to replace the newlines with `<br>`

Comment: I'm displaying it inside a CodeMirror editor, so I can't really do that

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find out how to do it. I just replaced the special character with << space >> and the line breaks with << newline >> and then in the python script just replaced them back. Thanks for helping anyways!